# If I have a case with 2 subcases should I use 1 or 2 Use Cases?

Tags: object-oriented, use-case, modeling

Let's say I have this example. There is a chef (actor) and a Use Case cook food. If there are 2 food options to cook (lets say pasta and pizza). Should I create 1 Use Case : CookFood and then in variations section add Pasta and Pizza, or should I create 2 use cases : CookPasta and CookPizza.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  With the information you've provided it's impossible to give you an answer that isn't entirely opinion based.

Comment: Maybe I am being pedantic about this, but I don't think that "Cook Food" is a use case, it sounds more like a solution to a use case.  A use case in my mind would be to prevent hunger pangs of the client, or something along that lines.  Cook food is more of a task than a use case.

Comment: @Matthew Use cases describe how external actors interact with the system. If the system is a stove, then “as a cook, I can cook food” is a use case. If the system is a restaurant, cooking food isn't a use case, but something that happens within the system. “As a customer, I can order food” would be a valid use case for the restaurant system. So it all depends on where the system boundary is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, the point of writing a use case is to communicate.

If you write a document that says: use case - actor cooks food. It isn't very interesting.  If this use case is part of a list of the many duties of a chef: manage employees, order food, prepare for health inspection, then it's a bit more interesting.

If the cooking pizza and pasta use cases are identical at the level your working, leaving the use case as simply cooking food is fine.

If, however, you need use cases with more detail, that show required equipment such as ovens and pots, then 'cook food' is too abstract.

If which you need isn't obvious to you then you're likely only making this use case on faith that there is a reason to.  Don't work on faith.  Question exactly what this is needed for until you understand why you're making it.  Then you'll know what you need to communicate.

Answer (score 2):

**Do we have all the elements ?**

Taking the definition of Ivar Jacobson , the original [inventor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case#History) of the use case modeling [(page 4 of his free e-book)](https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook):

> A use case is all the ways of using a system to achieve a particular
>   goal for a particular user.
>
> Taken together the set of all the use cases gives you all of the
>   useful ways to use the system, and illustrates the value  that it will
>   provide.

For the moment, you have identified the primary actor (the chief) and some potential use cases, but you've not told us anything on the most important start of our analysis:  what's the system under consideration ?

**What level of detail are you looking for ?**

[Cockburn](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Use+case+fundamentals#discussion) has elaborated on use cases (in his book "Writing effective use cases"):

> We have seen that both the goals and the interactions in a scenario
>   can be unfolded into finer and  finer-grained goals and interactions.

He identified that there are different [level of goals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case#Goal_levels) (and hence, different level of use cases):

- high level goals (he calls them cloud and kitten): these use cases give a very high level overview of the system's goals (e.g. operate a restaurant, subdivided in manage the room and manage the kitchen) and broad categories of actors (e.g. staff, customers, suppliers)
- user goals (he calls them see level): this is typically the "cook food level"
- sub-function goals (he calls the indigo, as you're now under the see level):  this is a further decomposition of the user goals.

**What' the purpose of your use case ?**

The next question is what is your use case for:

- do you want to know which use case to put on the UML diagram ?
- or do you want to [describe the use cases](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Basic+use+case+template) more in detail, in order to write specifications.

Not knowing what system we are talking of, what your intent is, and what level of detail you need therefore, it's difficult to objectively evaluate what would be the best alternative for you.

Furthermore, Jacobson and other recommend to look for use case by considering value.  Of course, it's not the value of interest for us, but it's the value of the use case for the user.

***Informal discussion / opinion***

Spontaneously, if looking at user-level, I'd see "cooking food" as the prime candidate for the use case.  Coming from an ERP background, I'd see Pasta and Pizza only as entities/data, as well as the recipes to make them (if you're not familiar with cooking or process industries, the manufacturing equivalent for a recipe would be a BOM + a routing)

If there would be a requirement to describe the difference in process between "cook Pizza" and "cook Pasta", I'd present them as a sub variant in a Cockburn like use case (scenario).  But nothing prevents you from showing all the three with the generalisation relationships.

Answer (score 0):

JAAAY, I bet you feel that you can't decide between two options, both of them seem to have pros and cons. That's true, it is a false dilemma. All of the use cases are perfectly valid since they are on different levels.

`Write all 3 use cases, no need to choose.`

There is a specific reason why I do not recommend to omit any of 'CookFood' and 'CookPasta'. Since you actually had such a thought it means that somewhere in your mind you already understand that there is something important and distinctive in each of them. It might be (guessing here) because 'CookFood' use case is crucial for business team and 'CookPasta' is something they don't even want to hear about. But development team is eager to receive 'CookPasta' while still having 'CookFood' for the big picture.

Have a look at an example below. I skipped most of the stuff to illustrate the idea, write use cases in a style which suites best your situation including their levels.

---

Scenario 1 (summary level): **Chief does his job**
Chief performs any of the following steps in arbitrary order any number of times:

1. Chief manages cooks.
2. Chief updates menu.
3. **Cook prepares a meal**.

---

Scenario 2 (user goal level): **Cook prepares a meal**

1. Cook picks a meal from the kitchen queue.
2. Cook picks ingredients.
3. Cook performs one of the following according to the meal picked:

   1. **Cook prepares pasta**.
   2. Cook prepares pizza.
   3. Trainee prepares a toast.
4. Cook delivers the meal to servants queue.

---

Scenario 3 (subfunction level): **Cook prepares pasta**

1. Cook picks boiled pasta.
2. Cook prepares a dressing.
3. Cook mixes them up.
4. Cook warms up the pasta in a microwave for a minute.